# No component factory found for ModalBackdropComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular

I am getting this error,

> No component factory found for ModalBackdropComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

I tried adding the ModalBackdropComponent as a entryComponents as that seems to be a common issue.  I also added the forRoot() on the end.  I am on angular 8

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { JobsRoutingModule, JobsRoutingDeceleration } from './jobs-routing.module';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-scrollbar';

import { ModalBackdropComponent, ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';
import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { AutocompleteLibModule } from 'angular-ng-autocomplete';
import { NgxPrintModule } from 'ngx-print';
import { AssignedJobWidgetComponent } from './jobs/assigned-job-widget/assigned-job-widget.component';

const modulesImport = [
    DragDropModule,
    NgxPrintModule,
  BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
  BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
  PaginationModule.forRoot(),
  ModalModule.forRoot(),
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    JobsRoutingDeceleration,
    AssignedJobWidgetComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    JobsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgScrollbarModule,
    OrderModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
      modulesImport,
      AutocompleteLibModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [ModalBackdropComponent],
})
export class JobsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I figured this `ModalBackdropComponent` was something that you yourself made.

You can remove it from `declarations` and `entryComponents` array. This must already have been done at `ngx-bootstrap` level.

Why do you need to explicitly import this component? Just importing `ModalModule` should do the trick for you.

If it still doesn't work, try checking the version of `ngx-bootstrap` version and any related issues.
I found this [stakcblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal-backdrop-click-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) which might be useful.

Comment: I added that and now see this error

'''ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type ModalBackdropComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ModalModule and JobsModule! Please consider moving ModalBackdropComponent to a higher module that imports ModalModule and JobsModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ModalBackdropComponent then import that NgModule in ModalModule and JobsModule.'''